# SOLR 7 : Broken pipe while uploading large file through /.system/blob/test api

Tags: solr, blob

Seeing the following exception on Solr 7 instance :

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)

at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:160)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:113)
at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
```

using these options to ensure the blob size limit has not reached..

-Dblob.max.size.mb=200 -Denable.runtime.lib=true

Uploading a jar file of size 170MB to a solrcloud instance running on localhost.

Also, this exception is often followed by the entire solr  instance becoming unresponsive with nothing in solr.log

Comment: Is this the log from the server or from the client submitting the blob?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes the log is from the client.. there is nothing in /server/solr.log